# Android, identify when is open/close the collapsingtoolbar

Tags: android, material-design

I've got a little problem and just can deal with it.
I'm doing an Android app with a collapsing toolbar. So, when it's open I put a sort of drawable image doing some gradient, like this, I can also use white images and still see the back arrow.
The problem is when I close the collapsing toolbar, because, the toolbar keeps the gradient giving an undesirable effect.
So I thought, if I can know programmatically when it is open or close, I can also change the toolbar color when it is closed. That's the problem, I just couldn't find a method which returns this.
So is there any option to know it? Know when it is collapsed or not.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener.html)

It has vertical offset parameter, which you can use to determine wether it's collapsed or not.

EDIT: Implement `onOffsetChanged` method:

```
if (collapsingToolbarLayout.getHeight() + verticalOffset < 2 * ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(collapsingToolbarLayout)) {
    //closed
} else {
    //opened
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your answer. But I still can find out how does it work. I can't get any vetical parameter. Can you please, give me some more explanations.

Comment: Thanks...it works perfectly. I think  I should re-study some java and android concepts...lack of experience on all these...thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have implement AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener in your activity. And there is method onOffsetChanged(final AppBarLayout appBarLayout, final int offset) inside the listener. 
You can simply identify whether the it is collapsed or not with the value of offset.

```
   if (offset == 0) {
    // completely opened state
    } else {
      // 
    }
```

you can also check whether it is completely collapsed with the following check inside the method:

```
 if (collapsingToolbar.getHeight() + offset < 2 *ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(collapsingToolbar){
  //completely collapsed state
  }
```

Comment: Thanks....now it's working....instead if I open and close it too fast sometimes it bugs...but for now is really more then enough!
My goal is to do something like hoteltonight....not commercial only for the know how!